# Can I use teleop in p2os system with only one computer instead a computer emisor and a computer receptor?

Tags: ros, teleop-base, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use teleop in p2os system with only one computer instead a computer emisor and a computer receptor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10337/can-i-use-teleop-in-p2os-system-with-only-one-computer-instead-a-computer-emisor-and-a-computer-receptor?/) by [albertocs](https://answers.ros.org/users/724/albertocs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That should be possible. You'll want to run everything described in the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20p2os) on the computer on the robot, and you'll have to attach your joystick to computer on the robot.

You shouldn't have to set ROS_MASTER_URI since all of your ros nodes are running on the same computer.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0